# How could I calculate the destination arrival time?

Tags: calculus

I am a programmer that is working on a unity project.

I have a drone that goes from a point A to a point B.
I know the fraction of the journey he did.
I know the time when he did that distance.
The speed is not constant, it is defined by

```
float smooth = 1.0f - Mathf.Pow(0.5f, Time.deltaTime * Speed);
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, PositionToGo, smooth); // position of my object is equal to Lerp of actual position and my destination
```

Time.deltaTime is the time elapsed since last frame.

The information I need to know is the duration of the drone journey in seconds.

Full source code

```
    float distCovered = (Time.time - startTime); 
    float fracJourney = distCovered / journeyLength;// Number between 0 and 1 representing the fraction of the jourey my drone did

    float smooth = 1.0f - Mathf.Pow(0.5f, Time.deltaTime * Speed);
    if (fracJourney >= 1) // if journey is over
    {
        Idle = true;
        StartCoroutine(IdleInPosition());// dont move
    }
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, PositionToGo, smooth); // position of my object is equal to Lerp of actual position and my destination
    SpeedTimer += Time.deltaTime;
    float dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, OldPosition);
    float speed = dist / Time.deltaTime;
    float JOURNEYLENGTH = // What should I put there ? 
    float y = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.PI * ((Time.time - startTime) / JOURNEYLENGTH));
    float rot = 20 * y / 1;
    Vector3 direction = transform.position - OldPosition;
    if (AngleDir(transform.forward, direction, Vector3.up) == -1)
        rot = -rot;
    transform.RotateAround(transform.position, Vector3.forward, rot);
    OldPosition = transform.position;
    SpeedTimer = 0;
```

Comment: If you have the distance and the time traveled, you only can know the average velocity of the travel, nothing more.

Comment: @hyprfrco Yes, I already tried with the average value. Problem is my speed is high in the beginning, and very slow at the end. So average speed doesn't fit me, isn't there any way I can't find the arrival time ?

Comment: This is solved through kalman filter by integrating the speed vectorially. But i doubt from a drone you will get a good results from that, the speed sensors will be too noisy. The best you can do is picking the GPS coordinates.

Comment: Lets pick it clear. From a drone you can get the arrival and departure time, or the elapsed time. And the GPS coordinates. Why you are inverting the problem?

Comment: @hyprfrco Sorry, I poorly formulated my question. I try to simulate a drone behaviour in a Unity (3D engine) project.

Comment: DO you have any knowledge of a drone? Have you flight one before??

Comment: Well yes I have, but it is not the question. In my code, I just need to calculate the estimated arrival time. The mouvement of my object will always stay the same, it's defined by 
    float smooth = 1.0f - Mathf.Pow(0.5f, Time.deltaTime * Speed);
and
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, PositionToGo, smooth);
Lerp linearly interpolates between two vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Having the distance position $x(t)$, in function of time, the velocity is:

$$
v(t)=\frac{dx}{dt} 
$$

and taking the differentials:
$$
dt=\frac{1}{v(t)}dx
$$

Hence taking the position as parameter instead of the time, the total time can be found as:
$$
t=\int_0^x \frac{1}{v(x)}dx \approx \frac{x}{v} 
$$

If $v$ is only a rough estimate from the real velocity, then the estimated time of course will also be a rough estimate.